# Inserting decimals as 0.00000000

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, double

I've got an issue when inserting double values into an ms-access database.

I've set the field, `size`, to be Currency type with 7 decimal places.

In my code, I have the following line to add the value to the query

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@size", OleDbType.Double).Value = CDbl(txt_size.Text)
```

When debugging, I can see the value in the @size parameter is 0.000008, which is what I typed into the text box.

Yet, when I view the record in access after the query has run, it shows as 0.0000000, and therefore when viewing the value in the application is shows as 0.0000 as well.

Why is it rounding the value down? Do I need to change something in Access to allow such small numbers?

Comment: Maybe an issue with floatingpoint inaccuracy

Comment: Why are you not defining the parameter as OleDbType.Currency if the Access type is Currency?  The Currency type maps to the .Net type System.Decimal.

Comment: @TnTinMn I've changed it to currency and it still does the same thing

Comment: @Detonar How would I check/fix that?

Comment: @David You could try if other values get changed. Count up `0.000009`, `0.000010`, `0.000011` etc. and see if those values also change and if yes, to what they change.

Comment: When changing it to decimal, make sure you're also changing `CDbl(txt_size.Text)` to `CDec(txt_size.Text)` to avoid additional errors and typecasting

Comment: @Detonar 0.000050 rounds down to 0.000000, whereas 0.000051 rounded up to 0.0001

Comment: @TnTinMn That still rounds it down to 0.000000. It seems to always round down to this unless the value entered is 0.000051 or greater

Comment: @David I'm not very used to ms access but it could be possible the used floating point type does not support the size you wish. Maybe you can change the data type in your database to something bigger-sized.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth That still rounds it down to 0.000000. It seems to always round down to this unless the value entered is 0.000051 or greater

Comment: This isn't even the usual behavior of a floating point variable, more like a fixpoint variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The currency data type doesn't support values that precise.

See [this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-data-types-and-field-properties-30ad644f-946c-442e-8bd2-be067361987c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#refcurrency) for a description of the currency type. It supports 4 decimals.

In formatting, you can of course increase the amount of decimals displayed, but that doesn't increase the size of the field.

If possible, I'd change the field to a double precision float or a decimal field (data type Number, field size Decimal). Both these types support higher precision than currency.